# Use MicroSD to SD adapter for read Memory Stick Micro M2

Tags: memory, sd

While searching in my personal affairs I found a `Memory Stick Micro M2 (Sony)` which I believe I was using in a phone. Unfortunately I no longer have the adapter that goes with it and it does not have the same format as a MicroSD. My goal is to use a MicroSD to SD adapter to try to read its content. Here is where I am in the material analysis.

[image]

The original adapter seem's to look like this

[image]

[image]
Is the pin identification correct and can I use this scheme to get to read the data or will it not work due to protocol, required supply voltage or other ? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Sounds like a lot of work. The value of the card is unlikely to be worth the effort . Consider finding someone who can read the card directly and transfer any contents to a different device / memory. eg a phone or camera that accepts the memory stick will often be able to be accessed as a USB mass storage device to allow data access.

Comment: Thank you. But because the format is old and specific to PSP and Cameras, I can't find someone who can read the card, that's why I would like to try to read it for myself.

Comment: What makes you think the cards would be compatible at all? The protocols are probably different and completely incompatible. If it was possible to use an adapter, someone would surely be selling them.

Comment: @akwky, Thank you. An [adapter](https://www.dhresource.com/0x0/f2/albu/g6/M00/7D/A8/rBVaR1sD-QGAbqkOAAMc-pd0vLY519.jpg) seems to exist.

Comment: @Ephemeral That "adapter" may have differing electronic circuitry to interface between the reader and either the memory stick card and the SD card. The card MAY just have a remapping of the contacts but this is uncertain and even unlikely. That "adapter" is a "card reader". They will be available and you really only need it for a one time use.  Where are you located? I have cameras that use the larger size memory stick but they are obsolete for practical purposes.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon, Thank you, you are probably right. I just saw that this kind of memory also has a `Serial Interface` and that its operating voltage is `2.7V / 3.6V`. I will try to read it with my Arduino (5V) using a voltage divider or my RaspberyPi (3.3V) using the SPI libraries because I not only want to recover the content of the card, I also want to access the FAT(s) and boot parameters in the first sector to learn about FAT. Thank you for your information.

Comment: @Ephemeral Ah, so you don't really need the data but just want to learn/experiment/have fun with it? If so, I'd hugely recommend microSD cards. If you manage to learn MemoryStick and need storage in your future projects, you'll have trouble buying more MemoryStick cards. MicroSDs are dirt cheap nowadays and you easily get help online on them. By the way, do not use voltage divider to power any card, it needs way too much current. Voltage regulator is needed.